# Reset frontpage after changing it to user

Tags: uri

I wanted my drupal site content to only be accessed by users who login.
I have a front-page which works fine:   "mysite.com/"
I want users to be re-directed to: 
"mysite.com/user"  or   "mysite.com/?q=user"

So, I went into the Admin > Site Configuration > and changed the front page to be /user

Unfortunately, my home page is exactly the same, no change there, and now I can't access the login to get back in as an Admin.

So, there are two questions:

1) How do I go into the database to reset this setting by hand, or is there a php file I have to go into?

2) Once I get my home page back, and the /?q=user page working again, how can I force users to that page to login before anything that happens.

This is Drupal 7 ... I remember Drupal 5 and 6 being so much easier to manage.

I am also using the MD Apline theme if that matters ....

Thanks for any help!
                               Tom

Answer (score 1):

That's a pickle. This should get you out of it:

`drush vset site_frontpage node`

Or if you don't have access to drush (why would you use drupal without drush?) you can run this sql:

`DELETE FROM variable WHERE name = 'site_frontpage'`

Comment: The website is hosted on HostGator, and I don't know if I can use drush there.   I don't think I have access to any kind of command line.   I wish I did, or maybe I have access to it, and I don't know it.  What I DO have access to is the site via FTP and then I can also access the database as well.   That's my key to fixing this.   What does the Drush command fix in the file or database that I can do manually?

Comment: Ok, updated with a sql-only solution. Upvotes on these answers would be most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. Rather than replacing your front-page with a system form (which seems like a bad idea, since that form will give "access denied" to authenticated users) you can set loginToboggan to display a login form on any page that anonymous users do not have access to.

Comment: sure .... another answer I found for Drupal 7 is to simply remove the 'view published content' permission for the anonymous role.   I will give this a try.  In the meantime, I still need to know how to reset the front page back to it's default.  I am guessing this gets set in a php file or filed to the database.   I need to be able to get back in to login.